# Storing objects in vector

Tags: c++, libstdc++

Is it possible to have a vector without specializing it?

My problem is: I have an abstract class N4GestureRecognizer
and a couple of subclasses of it.
So in a Controller class I want to have a `vector<N4GestureRecognizer> recognizers_` but since it is abstract I cannot.
How can I store this recognizers in a vector or collection or list or whatever is loop-able in standard c++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store them as pointers. Either pure pointers or some smart pointer class.

**EXTRA**
Actually, pointers are the only way even if the class is not abstracts, but is subclassed and child classes are intended to be used in the vector. Why: std::vector allocates sizeof(T) bytes for each element, but sizeof(derivedFromT) could be bigger than sizeof(T). You will be able to push a child object into the vector, but it can cause unpredictable issues at run time.

Managing vectors of pointers is a pain, of course, but as far as I remember, boost contains some smart pointers to simplify the task.

Comment: I'm afraid it's the only way.

Comment: And these days the standard has smart pointers: std::tr1::shared_ptr<>

Comment: The result at runtime of pushing derived classes into a vector like this is not "unpredictable".  It's called slicing, and it is quite predictable (though maybe unexpected by a novice).

Comment: The slicing itself it predictable :) I mean that executing of the app won't be predictable.

Comment: Let me point out: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<N4GestureRecognizer> >`.

If your std lib comes without `std::shared_ptr` (it's part of the next C++ standard, expected to be published next year), it might come with `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, which is the same (as a addition to the current C++ standard by the official *Technical Report 1*). If that also fails, there's always [boost](http://www.boost.org), which has `boost:shared_ptr` (which is the predecessor of `std::tr1::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`).

*Note:* Don't use naked pointers (`std::vector<N4GestureRecognizer*>`). There's almost no way to make this safe so that it doesn't leak.

Comment: Although if you can use boost, `ptr_vector` is often a better solution than a `std::vector` of `shared_ptr`.